# TFS 2010 and new branch, contains partial changeset from before the branch was made, how? why? what can/should we do?

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS branch for our main product that on march 21st was branched to create a branch for maintenance of a specific version of the product.

The timeline looks like this:

- changeset up to 37099 is on main branch
- changeset 37100 is the branch changeset creating the maintenance branch

After this we have done development on the main branch, both for future versions and bugfixes intended for the maintenance branch, that has been merged.

Today we noticed that the dialog in Visual Studio 2015 that shows unmerged changesets contains two changesets below 37100, from december last year.

[image: merge dialog oddity]

Tracking these changesets shows them as partial.

[image: track changeset]

[image: partial changes in a branch?]

Since we're in the process of upgrading to TFS 2015 this weekend we're just going to let this be but is this a known bug? Should we do something about it? How can a branch contain partial changes of historical changesets? Has anyone experienced the same thing and know what should be done, if anything?

Comment: We're currently just going to assume that the merge dialog (or the code on the server that works out the changesets to show) is confused and hope that TFS 2015 is better at working this out. This late in the upgrade cycle we're not going to do another test-run to verify this but will instead make a note of checking this during the upgrade, still, an answer to what we should do would be most welcome.

Comment: Those change sets were probably representing last time some of your files were edited. If I understand you correctly that happen after you merged your project. Since that was last time some files were truly edited those change sets apply. Makes sense when you updated files after some change sets. That way it will keep smaller size to those updates.